# How to optimize UITableViewCell, because my UITableView lags

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Ok, my `UITableView` is too complicated for loading. And when paging between `UIPageViewController`, then it lags, I cannot simply and fast swipe between pages. What is wrong?

**How doest it work?**

My `UIViewController` has `UITableView` with lot of cells. Those view controllers are part of `UIPageViewController`. Swiping between them... lags.

How can I optimize the app to speed it up?

I discovered that this is because of my `UITableViewCell`, when no cells, then it is simple... and works like a charm. But when cells are loaded, then it lags.

This is my `UITableViewCell`:

[image]
[image]

This is my `cellForRow:`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let address = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AddressTableViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell

    cell.configure(with: address)
    cell.isSelectionMode = isSelectionMode
    cell.isSelected = selectedAddresses.contains(address)

    return cell
}
```

and `AddressTableViewCell`:

```
class AddressTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var emptyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private var rejectedButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet private var dateForLastNoteLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var addressNoteLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var lastNoteLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var returnVisitImageView: AttributedImageView!
    @IBOutlet private var regularDeliveryImageView: AttributedImageView!
    @IBOutlet private var studyImageView: AttributedImageView!
    @IBOutlet private var emailImageView: AttributedImageView!
    @IBOutlet private var phoneNumberImageView: AttributedImageView!
    @IBOutlet private var actionButtonsWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet private var selectViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet private var selectView: AttributedView!

    private var address: Address!

    var isSelectionMode: Bool = false {

        didSet {

            emptyButton.isEnabled = !isSelectionMode
            rejectedButton.isEnabled = !isSelectionMode
            selectViewWidthConstraint.constant = isSelectionMode ? 50 : 0
            accessoryType = isSelectionMode ? .none : .disclosureIndicator
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {

        didSet {
            selectView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? Settings.shared.currentMode.homeColor : UIColor.clear
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Class Methods

    //MARK: - Initialization

    //MARK: - Deinitialization

    //MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func emptyButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        save(withStatus: [0, 2].contains(address.status) ? 1 : 0)
    }

    @IBAction func rejectButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        save(withStatus: [0, 1].contains(address.status) ? 2 : 0)
    }

    //MARK: - Open

    //MARK: - Internal

    func configure(with address: Address) {

        self.address = address

        let status = AddressStatus(rawValue: address.status)!

        addressNoteLabel.text = address.text
        nameLabel.text = address.name
        emptyButton.tintColor = status == .empty ? UIColor.black : UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        rejectedButton.tintColor = status == .rejected ? UIColor.red : UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        returnVisitImageView.isHidden = status != .returnVisit
        returnVisitImageView.topImageViewTintColor = Settings.shared.currentMode.homeColor
        regularDeliveryImageView.isHidden = !address.isRegularDelivery
        regularDeliveryImageView.topImageViewTintColor = Settings.shared.currentMode.homeColor
        studyImageView.isHidden = !address.isStudy
        studyImageView.topImageViewTintColor = Settings.shared.currentMode.homeColor
        emailImageView.isHidden = address.email == nil
        emailImageView.topImageViewTintColor = Settings.shared.currentMode.homeColor
        phoneNumberImageView.topImageViewTintColor = Settings.shared.currentMode.homeColor
        phoneNumberImageView.isHidden = address.phoneNumber == nil

        dateForLastNoteLabel.text = nil
        lastNoteLabel.text = nil
        actionButtonsWidthConstraint.constant = [AddressStatus.returnVisit, ].contains(status) || address.isStudy || address.isRegularDelivery ? 0 : 100

        if !returnVisitImageView.isHidden && address.lastNote == nil {
            dateForLastNoteLabel.text = "  "
        }

        if let note = address.lastNote {

            dateForLastNoteLabel.text = note.descriptiveDateAndTime
            lastNoteLabel.text = note.text
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Private

    private func save(withStatus status: Int16) {

        emptyButton.isEnabled = false
        rejectedButton.isEnabled = false

        MagicalRecord.save({ [weak self] context in

            self?.address.mr_(in: context)?.status = status

        }) { [weak self] _, error in

            guard let `self` = self else {
                return
            }

            UIAlertController.show(from: error)

            if error == nil {

                Sync.saveForSync(identifier: self.address.identifier, reason: 1)
                CloudAssistant.shared.performSyncing()
            }

            self.emptyButton.isEnabled = true
            self.rejectedButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Overridden
}
```

Comment: What code do you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? The issue is almost certainly not UI-related, but logic/API call related.

Comment: Everything is fetched from `NSFRC` and data is assigned to labels and some icons.

Comment: The cell has a lot of UI elements that is recalculate it's constraints every time the cellForRow method called , try to remove the stack views , and work it out without them.

Comment: Ok, I try and let you know... how does it work then...

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk have you given it a try?

Comment: I will check it later... cannot now;(

Comment: I suggest profiling the app with the Time Profiler.

Comment: @D.Mika profiling? How can I do that? You mean instruments?

Comment: @AymanIbrahim I did remove stackviews and it lags less, but still...

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk yes.

Answer (score 2):

1) Every `UIView` and subtype have `backgroundColor` by default transparent. Try to add on every view(view, button, image, stack) a white background color.

2)On your configure(with address: Address) check if you have not the same address.

3)Try to be sharp on constraint setting, the less you let `Autolayout` gets your layout, the less cpu is used.